# How do I loop through a row of data, pull value from specific cell in that row, find it in another row, then enter a value in the intersecting box

Tags: excel, vba

So i have a workbook. Rows 1-3 are header info. Row 4 starting in column C is dates from Jan 1 2020 to Dec 31, 2020. Then I have names of Employee's in Column A from A5:A:16. Then from B:5:B16 i have their start dates (formatted exactly the same as the dates in row 4). I am trying to loop through A:5-A:20 and if there is a name there, get the value from row B (Their start date) and find that value in row 4 (Which is where the dates are) to get the column, and then put a "n" in the cell that will intersect their name and start date.  But when i press my button or run my code, nothing happens.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim lnCol As Long

For i = 5 To Range("A20")
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
        StartDate = Cells(i, 2).Value

        lnCol = Sheet3.Cells(4, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:=StartDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).column

        Cells(i, lnCol).Value = "n"


    End If


Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect Range("A20") is not a number. So this line wont work For i = 5 To Range("A20"). First For loop need an initial value like 5 and an ending value like 15. This will make looping through rows as you’re expecting.  You can also use F8 key to step line by line through your code

Comment: It's funny it wouldn't raise an error 13 actually. Since you say you got names in `A5:A20`. I assume `A20` is empty then? Then will evaluate to a zero. Meaning you iterate from 5-0, which means it will skip the iteration completely.

Comment: Yes right now only A5:A16 are filled. I wanted to make the formula search a larger range for when we add people.

Comment: I see, well I think then you need a dynamic way to retrieve the last filled cell. I'll edit my answer. That's better than a check for empty cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim cl As Range
Dim col As Long

With Sheet1 'Change to sheets CodeName you interested in
    For Each cl In .Range("A5:A20").SpecialCells(2, 2)
        col = .Range("4:4").Find(What:=cl.Offset(, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        .Cells(cl.Row, col).Value = "n"
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

<sub>**Note:** `.Range("A5:A20").SpecialCells(2, 2)` will only work when you positive there is at least one name. This prevents a full iteration. However, when all are empty will raise an error</sub>

---

***Edit***

According to your comment:

> *"Yes right now only A5:A16 are filled. I wanted to make the formula search a larger range for when we add people."*

I think what you actually wanted is a dynamic way to retrieve the last used row. In that case try the below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim cl As Range
Dim col As Long

With Sheet1 'Change to sheets CodeName you interested in
    For Each cl In .Range("A5:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        col = .Range("4:4").Find(What:=cl.Offset(, 1).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        .Cells(cl.Row, col).Value = "n"
    Next cl
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Lzypenguin, please if this has worked, consider to upvote/accept the answer to return the favor and close the thread

Comment: I have accepted it as the answer but not sure how to close the thread.